# why the select query behaviour is different with single quotes in where condition and without single quotes

Tags: mysql, sql, plsql, plsqldeveloper

I have observed different behaviours when executing a query with single quotes and without single quotes.

With single quotes (`'121'`) I got the result quickly and query is using index well.  But without single quotes, the query is not using the index and response time is high.

```
mysql> explain  select * from tbl_n1 where id =121;
+----+-------------+----------------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+--------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table                | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows   | Extra       |
+----+-------------+----------------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+--------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | tbl_n1               | ALL  | n1_id      | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 286929 | Using where |
+----+-------------+----------------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+--------+-------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> explain  select * from tbl_n1 where id ='121';
+----+-------------+----------------------+------+---------------+----------+---------+-------+------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table                | type | possible_keys | key      | key_len | ref   | rows | Extra       |
+----+-------------+----------------------+------+---------------+----------+---------+-------+------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | tbl_n1               | ref  | n1_id       | n1_id  | 53      | const |   29 | Using where |
+----+-------------+----------------------+------+---------------+----------+---------+-------+------+-------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)


show create table tbl_n1\G
....
....
 `id` varchar(10)  DEFAULT NULL,
....
....
....
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since the definition of field `id` is `varchar`, without the single quotes the database will have to make an **implicit conversion** of the field `id` applying a cast (or whatever function to convert it to a varchar) which will prevent the use of the index `idx_1055`

Read this article about it: [Type Conversion in Expression Evaluation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/type-conversion.html)

Comment: I wonder why wouldn't it convert right-hand side value to string instead? In that case it could use index.

Comment: I agree still very weird. In postgres the implicit conversion would be a constant and still use the index.

Comment: Yeah, it could check what would be the best match and do the appropriated conversion so it uses the index. I guess that it is just the way the MySql guys implemented it.